# Why the variable time1 becoming Zero?

Tags: c

When I am getting some problem why `time1` variable getting zero. right after calculation of floor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
   int curfl = 0, destfl, floor;
   int time1, high, speed;
   high = 3;
   speed = 5;
   while(1)
   {
       printf("Currently the elevator is at floor number = %d\n", curfl);
       printf("Enter the floor number between 0-25 : ");
       scanf("%d", &destfl);
       if(destfl > curfl)


       {
               floor = destfl - curfl;
                /*****************************/
               time1 = (floor * (high / speed));  //variable become zero here
               /*****************************/
               printf("Elevator will take %d second to reach %d (st, nd, rd) floor \n", time1, destfl);
               while(curfl != destfl)
               {
               Sleep(1000 * 3 / 5);
               curfl++;
               printf("You are at floor number %d \n", curfl);
           }
           printf("Door opening \n");
           Sleep(10000);
           printf("Door Closed\n");
       }
       else if(destfl > curfl)
       {
           floor = curfl - destfl;
           time1 = (floor * (3 / 5));
           printf("Elevator will take %d second to reach %d (st, nd, rd) floor \n", time1, destfl);
           while(curfl != destfl)
           {
               Sleep(1000 * 3 / 5);
               curfl--;
               printf("You are at floor number %d \n", curfl);
           }
           printf("Door opening \n");
           Sleep(10000);
           printf("Door Closed\n");
       }
       else{
           printf("You are the same floor. Please getout from the elevator \n");
       }
}
   // printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing integer calculations. Switch to something that handles fractions.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into integer division. When you do arithmetic on integers, and the result will also be an integer. So something like 1 / 3 = 0 in integer-land. So when you do `(high / speed)`, the temporary result will be an integer, and if the answer is some decimal < 1, the result will be truncate simply to 0.

To fix this, you should change the code to use `float` or `double` instead `int`.

Comment: Well spotted! He's got `time1 = (floor*(3/5))` indeed, which would then equal `time1 = (floor*0)`

Answer (score 0):

calculate time1 like follows :

```
int curfl = 0, destfl, floor;
int high;
float speed, time1;
................................
time1 = (floor * (high / speed));
```

It looks like its for an embedded device. So don't know how it supports floating point operation.
if it does not support, pickup a divide algorithm, declare a type like following :

```
struct myfloat{
   int precision;
   int exponent;
}
```

and then write a divide function like :

```
struct myfloat * divide(int a, int b) /* gives result for a/b */
```